# How to use "range" in python to include not just numbers 1-1000, but have each number appear with 3 digits?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want to go through each number in the range 1-1000, but I need my program to be 3 digits. So 001, 002, 003,...,999. How can I do this?

Comment: Don't confuse data and its representation.

Answer (score 0):

You can format it to a string with leading zeroes:

```
for i in range(0, 1000):
    print "%03d" % (i)
```

Comment: And if you prefer using the new-style formatting: `'{:03}'.format(i)`. And if using f-strings it would be: `f'{i:03}'`.